# How to hide suggestion box?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to hide the suggestion list whenever user stops entering a query. Here are my code snippets -

Javascript -

```
 getsearchresults(searchquery) {

    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('QueryString', searchquery);
   // params.set('QueryClass', 'MaxHits=5');

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, search: params });
    return this.http
      .get(this.searchURL, options)
      .debounceTime(300)
      .map(response =>

        response.json()

      ).catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

HTML

```
<input #input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" id="nav-input" (keyup)="onquery($event)"
           [(ngModel)]="searchdata.query">
```

Another snippet from JS file

```
    onquery(event: any) {

    this.store.dispatch(new query.QueryAction(event.target.value));

    this.submit();
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I solve it? It would be great if anyone can help me out with this. :D

UPDATE:

Here is the screenshot of the error. After when a user finishes entering a query suggestion box is still there.
[image]

Comment: `store` which one you are using? `ngrx-store`??

Comment: Yes @Aravind :)

Comment: What's that u r getting on using the above code

Comment: No :) @Aravind Thanks though for giving time to my question! I really appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145290/discussion-between-aravind-and-harshit).